# Class member with template parameter that contains another template class with parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have a pointer to a B of C of T (example below). I'm trying to compile similar classes with g++ 3.4.0, but I'm getting the error message: "b was not declared in this scope". How do I achieve this in C++?

main.cpp:

```
template <class T> class B;
template <class T> class C;

template <class T>
class A
{
private:
    T* first;
    B<C<T>>* b;
};

template <class T>
class B
{
};

template <class T>
class C
{
};
```

Comment: Sure, why not? -

Comment: @Quentin I refined my question a bit. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: You'll want `B` and `C` to be at least declared before you use them.  Other than that, what's stopping you?

Comment: @aschepler I'm forward declaring them already (my example didn't show that). I'm getting "b was not declared in this scope"

Comment: So I have copy pasted your exact example and as I already assumed this code shouldn't and does not (VS17) give any errors with main function where I instantiated A<int>.

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: @MarošBeťko Ok, so gcc 3.4.0 is 13 years old or so. Could it just be that it wasn't possible at that time? :)

Comment: @aschepler does it qualify now? (I've compiled it in one file on my computer, no main function was necessary to get the compile error)

Comment: Are you compiling with a `-std=` flag?  The adjacent `>` characters are a problem in C++03.

Comment: No "-std=". However, what you said about the > could have been the answer. It seems to compile nicely if I add a space between the two >'s.... like this: B<C<T> >* b

Comment: @aschepler Yep, it compiles better. Thanks for your help. All of you.

Comment: Oh wow, 2004.  `-std=c++0x` probably isn't an option then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1998 and 2003 versions of C++, to close two template argument lists, or a template argument list and a C++-style cast, you must put a space between the `>` characters, to keep the tokenizer from parsing them as the `>>` token.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix;
std::vector<double> v = static_cast<std::vector<double> >(myobj);
```

The grammar specifies the argument list or cast type ends with a `>` token, and doesn't recognize a `>>` token as two of these.

In C++11, a rule was added to replace a `>>` token with two `>` tokens when inside a template argument list and outside of parentheses.  (So if you really meant right-shift, you must use parentheses.)

```
std::array<double, (16>>3)> arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people helping me out on this question, I was able to find a solution. It seems unnecessary, but I only had to add a space between the >'s, like this:

```
B<C<T> >* b;
```

(I'm not sure why. My initial thought was that it could be mistaken for the >> operator.)

Comment: GCC 3.4.0 is somewhat old. Only starting at C++11 can you omit that space, which GCC 3.4.0 does not support (by default, at least). In C++03 and earlier, `>>` was unconditionally parsed as 'right-shift' thus rendering the whole string senseless.